# How to create subclass view controller whose base class has storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, instantiation

I have a storyboard-based `UIViewController` called `BaseViewController` which has the same name as ID.

I have a simple subclass `MyViewController : BaseViewController` (which has no storyboard nor XIB).

I want to create a `MyViewController` such that it instantiates its base class `BaseViewController` from the storyboard.

I tried the following code:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboard", bundle: nil)
let viewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BaseViewController") as! MyViewController
```

Which of course, as pointed out by [Sh_Khan in answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62952069/1971013), doesn't work and results in: `Could not cast value of type 'myProject.BaseViewController' (0x...) to 'myProject.MyViewController' (0x...).`

How then can I create a `MyViewController` object?

Comment: You would need to create a scene in your storyboard that has `MyViewController` as its custom class

Comment: I was about to post an answer to your last question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can up cast meaning cast from child to parent but not vice versa the reason is simple child has all related data to parent so it can go to it easily but the parent doesn't know what the child has

Comment: Shoot, of course!  How then can I create a `MyViewController` such that it instantiates `BaseViewController` from the storyboard?

Comment: Don't think this is possible as finally you have to cast whether to the vc that you set as class name in IB or it's super class BTW you can tell your use case for this need if i can help about it ?